# VB.NET - Webbrowser Control - display label text

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to create a windows form with web browser control in it using VB.NET.

My form consists of a webbrowser control and a label.

I would like to change the text of label on finding an input name="gid_ost_go" to "Found it!"

Following is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://mywebsite-url")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
        theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
            If curElement.GetAttribute("name").Equals("gid_ost_go") Then
                Label1.Text = "Found it!"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above code does not work. The value of label1 does not change. However, I am able to find input tag with name="gid_ost_go" in source code of the page.

Also, I have changed the registery to emulate the webbrowser control to IE11. So all the scripts load fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I have multiple partial views being loaded onto my page and the mentioned tag is on one of those views. The event is not being loaded or caught as the text of the label does not change. So what I am trying to do is, when I click on the button whose name="gid_ost_go". I want form2 to be displayed. The source code of the page does show the input button whose name="gid_ost_go"

Comment: Your code looks fine. Does the page load correctly? Test it by using https://google.com as url, and `sclient` as the control name to find and it works. Make sure the control your looking for is an input control or it wont find it.

Comment: Document.complete is going to fire for all iframes and then the parent page. If that webpage has several iframes, then that even will fire multiple times. It is possible that you are getting to that event before what you want is loaded.

Comment: I have multiple views being loaded onto my page and the mentioned tag is on one of those views. The event is not being loaded or caught as the text of the label does not change. So what I am trying to do is, when I click on the button whose name="gid_ost_go". I want a form to be displayed.